# Oozie/yarn: resource changed on src filesystem

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie

I have an Oozie workflow, with one of its step being a java step, running a jar stored on the local filesystem (the jar is present on all nodes).

Initially, the jar was installed via a RPM, so they all have the same timestamp.

While experimenting, I manually copied a new version over this jar, and I now get the message:

```
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1516602562532_15451 to YARN : Application application_1516602562532_15451 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1516602562532_15451_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://ip-10-0-0-239.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1516602562532_15451 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: java.io.IOException: Resource file:/opt/tst/tst.jar changed on src filesystem (expected 1516886392000, was 1516891496000
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

The main line is:

> Resource file:/opt/tst/tst.jar changed on src filesystem (expected 1516886392000, was 151689149600).

The 2 numbers are timestamp, the `expected` one is indeed the TS of the old jar, identical on all servers, the `was` TS is the timestamp of the new jar on one of the datanodes (as they were `scp`'ed in a loop, the TS are slightly different).

My question is: how do I tell yarn to stop whinging and use the new one already?

A few notes:

- Hortonworks 2.6, based on hadoop 2.7,
- the jar is only put by me on the local FS, not in hdfs,
- nothing to do with spark (my issue comes up a lot on google related to spark),
- `yarn.sharedcache.enabled` is `false` (the default) so `yarn scmadmin -runCleanerTask` is not relevant here,
- I could fix my current problem by just reusing the old jar and I could make sure that all DNs have the same TS, but I wonder how I would ever be able to use a new version (note that the jar pointed by oozie is a symlink to not have to update oozie when a new version is released),
- I'd rather keep the file on the local FS instead of having to put it on hdfs,
- the jar name is quite specific, it does no clash with any other jar,
- the workflow runs as user `yarn` and I can't find any copy of my jar in the yarn user directory on hdfs (nor under oozie dir for that matter),
- I can find copies of the jar under the yarn local dir /filecache, but their md5 do not match any of my (current) versions.

Comment: What specifically do you have against putting the jar on HDFS? Seems less overhead than looping an SCP job

Comment: @cricket_007 Our current deployment pipeline works with rpm, where it is basically free of work for me to install a jar on all servers. Having to update it to put the jar in hdfs is doable of course but I would rather not do the extra work, my todo list is big enough as it is. Furthermore, I really would like to understand the core of the problem.

Comment: @Guillaume I'm coming across the same kind of issue. Did you figure it out, in the end?

Comment: @Poorkenny The master plan ended up being 'just wait a bit'. In my case the jar is tiny and not updated often, so pragmatically this is the best for us. Sorry, this is probably not the answer you hoped for.

Comment: @Guillaume Indeed, it's not ^^ Thanks for answering, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents, you can build `yarn` related jar yourself and add it to your current working environment.

It's could be a workaround to skip this "annoying" condition checking.

Generally steps are as below:

1, Get the source code of yarn you used. You can download it from Hadoop official site. 
2, Search error log like `changed on file system` in Hadoop source code.
3, Comment it out
4, Rebuild Yarn related jar
5, Put it to your working environment.

You can refer to [How to fix resource changed on src filesystem issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300578/how-to-fix-resource-changed-on-src-filesystem-issue/58405426#58405426) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, in my case with an output folder. (*Resource path/to/output/folder changed on src filesystem (expected 1583243472154, was 1583243577395)*) when running a Pig script in a Oozie workflow.

Removing the **.staging** folder fixed my problem.